# JodaTime throws IllegalArgumentException with Date string from EXIF metadata

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I'm writing some code to store metadata from uploaded images in the database.  One of those fields is the photo Capture Date.  The [API I'm using](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) returns the Capture Date in the String format

```
Sat Nov 01 20:08:07 UTC 2014
```

However, Joda Time throws an IllegalArgumentException when creating a `DateTime` or `LocalDateTime`.  Conversely, `java.util.Date` accepts the string formatting and creates a `Date` object with no issue.

One solution is to do

```
Date tempDate = new Date("Sat Nov 01 20:08:07 UTC 2014");
DateTime captureDate = new DateTime(tempDate);
```

but this requires creating two separate objects to persist one.  Given the string format above, is it possible to convince JodaTime to create a `DateTime` object without an intermediary `Date` initialization?

Comment: Are you currently just calling `new DateTime(text)`?

Comment: Correct.  This question is a specialized followup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136877/joda-time-datetime-invalid-format-with-spring.

Comment: Right. It's always useful to give an example of the code that isn't working within your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Joda Time `DateTime` and `LocalDate` constructors which take `Object` have documentation including:

> The String formats are described by `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.

The text you're providing is *not* in an ISO format.

Instead, you should create a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the format you're using, e.g. via [`DateTimeFormat.forPattern`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)), specifying the locale, time zone etc. (It's not clear from your example whether it's *always* going to be in UTC, or whether you need time zone handling.)

For example:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_PARSER =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC' yyyy")
        .withLocale(Locale.US)
        .withZoneUTC();

...

DateTime dateTime = DATETIME_PARSER.parseDateTime(text);
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I came across similar code snippets looking for a solution, but the missing piece was the pattern for the formatter, particularly the EEE and 'UTC' inclusions.

Comment: @Jason: Well `EEE` is just the documented "short day of week as text"; The `'UTC'` is an escaped literal.

Comment: Exactly, but due to not uncovering a concrete example implementation combined with missing these specifics in the documentation resulted in me backtracking to a regular Date object.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: I’d certainly prefer to parse the time zone abbreviation as such using the pattern `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. The we no longer need `.withZoneUTC()`. Also when this works for very few time zone abbreviation. And also when Arvind Kumar Avinash is right in the other answer: we should be migrating our Joda-Time code to java.time by now.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Do not use a fixed text for the timezone:

Do not use a fixed text (e.g. `'UTC'`) for the timezone because that approach may fail for other locales.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Sat Nov 01 20:08:07 UTC 2014";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s z u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-11-01T20:08:07Z[Etc/UTC]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EUVuJF)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Just for the sake of completeness

Just for the sake of completeness, I have written the following solution using Joda Date-Time API:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Sat Nov 01 20:08:07 UTC 2014";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E MMM d H:m:s z y").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(dt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-11-01T20:08:07.000Z
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>